# javascript readline stream close event doesn't get triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, readline

I am trying to learn javascript streams and trying to transform lines into objects. Here I am streaming from a s3 file by getObject, I am able to transform lines into json format, however, I am not able to see `close` event triggered for readline.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var readline = require('readline');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var outstream = new (require('stream'))()

var s3 = new aws.S3({
    apiVersion: "2006-03-01",
    accessKeyId: "foobar",
    secretAccessKey: "foobar"
});

var readParams = {
    Bucket : "bucket", // name of the bucket
    Key: "key" // exact file name
}

var readStream = s3.getObject(readParams).createReadStream();

var lineReader = readline.createInterface({
    input: readStream,
    output: outstream
});

var record = {};
var result = [];
lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
    var lineStr = line.toString();
    if (lineStr.includes("EOE")) {
        result.push(record);
        record = {};
        lineReader.pause();
    } else {
        lineReader.resume();
    }
    var strArr = lineStr.split("=");
    var key = strArr[0];
    var value = strArr[1];
    if(key === 'RequestID' || key === 'StartTime' || key === 'Time' || key === 'Operation') {
        value = value.trim().replace(" ms", "");
        record[[key]] = value;
    }
}).on('close', function() {
    console.log("Finished");
});
```

I am not able to see "Finished" when I am done with streaming s3 get request. Thanks for your help

Comment: I vaguely remember something like this; can you try `'end'` instead of `'close'`?

Comment: nope no chance.

Comment: The logic seems odd to me... When you pause the reader for the first time how it will be resumed?

Comment: @alex-rokabilis hi alex it was my bad that I haven't known how streams are working with pause and resume. I post an answer with the correct way. now I am able to use close event. thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing `linereader.pause()` and `linereader.resume()` lines. I thought the way pause and resume are working if line contains EOE pause the reader and skip that line. process record and continue if line doesn't contains EOE. so basically here is the working code.

```
lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
    var lineStr = line.toString();
    if (lineStr.includes("EOE")) {
        result.push(record);
        record = {};
    } else {
        var strArr = lineStr.split("=");
        var key = strArr[0];
        var value = strArr[1];
        if(key === 'RequestID' || key === 'StartTime' || key === 'Time' || key === 'Operation') {
            value = value.trim().replace(" ms", "");
            record[[key]] = value;
        }
    }
}).on('close', function() {
    console.log("Finished");
});
```

Thanks for all helping!